# connecting SQL server 2016 with django but getting error of Login failed for user username odbc azure

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I am trying to connect sql-server version 2016 with django framework and when  connecting SQL server management studio with right credentials then showing all database in it but when trying to do all this with django getting error   and I have install `pyodbc` using pip and also install `pyodbc-azure` then setting database connectivity

Tried to make new user and gave access to everything but getting same error

`'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'oms',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'HOST': 'ADMINRG-EDOFT5N',
        'USER': 'vikas',
        'PASSWORD': '111111',
        'DRIVER': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'
    }`
But getting error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'deepak' odbc-azure

Comment: 'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },

Comment: did it  but getting same error , i am getting sql-server studio error that  login failed for user by the way thank you sir

Comment: when creating new user in ssms give them all grant and then try to connect with it

Comment: @Raj already did it but still get the same error

Comment: Have you logged into the correct domain? As per Microsoft it can not verify user when the login is from untrusted domain.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi yes sir i have followed as possible conventions